# PHP/MySQL select if value is between the value of two rows?

Tags: php, mysql

Playing around with some php and MySQL however I'm having some issues. I've got a table that looks like:

```
----------------------------
| level  | exp             |
----------------------------
| 1      | 0               |
----------------------------
| 2      | 10              |
----------------------------
| 3      | 20              |
----------------------------
| 4      | 30              |
----------------------------
| 5      | 40              |
----------------------------
```

I'm trying to figure out how I would select a level depending on the variable input so far I've got:

```
$sql = "SELECT level FROM levels WHERE exp >= $miningexp LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $db->query($sql);
$row =$stmt->fetchObject();
$mininglevel = $row->level;
```

Now if for example if the $miningexp is set to 9 I'd expect the output of level = 1. However it is outputting level = 2.

Not sure if this makes sense what I'm trying to do some more examples of what should be output:

```
If $miningexp = 11 Then $mininglevel = 2
If $miningexp = 15 Then $mininglevel = 2
If $miningexp = 19 Then $mininglevel = 2
If $miningexp = 20 Then $mininglevel = 3
If $miningexp = 25 Then $mininglevel = 3
If $miningexp = 35 Then $mininglevel = 4
```

Anyone got any ideas/or guidance? Thanks!

Comment: I think level 2 is the correct answer based on the query that you posted (10 >= 9)

Comment: Likewise, I am not sure if the additional examples that you posted are correct since if `$miningexp = 11` then 20 >= 11 so the query should give you 3 as the level and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what sort of select query would give the output I'm looking for?

Comment: Try this: `$sql = "SELECT level FROM levels WHERE exp <= $miningexp ORDER BY LEVEL DESC LIMIT 1";` ?

Comment: That outputs 1 every time as its the first result.

Comment: I made updates to the query in the comment. Please try the updated one now.

Comment: Perfect! thank you, do you want to post it as an answer and i'll accept it.

Comment: Nah. It's okay. It helped you so that's all that matters. It was a simple fix anyway.